# is it possible to inherits object from object by using Literal notation way?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, object-literal

in short : is it possible to inherits object from object by using `Literal notation` way, or we must  use `Constructor` way  ?

**For example:** (Literal way)

```
var obj = {}, obj2 = {};

obj.str = "hello world!";
obj.printTxt = function () {
    console.log(this.str);
};

obj2.prototype = obj.prototype; // occurs error message `(TypeError: obj2.printTxt is not a function)`
obj2.printTxt();
```

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem with your "literal notation" example is that `obj.prototype` does not exist.  Objects do not have a meaningful property named `prototype`.  The relationship between the object and its prototype is opaque and immutable - there is no standard way to determine what the prototype is, and there is no standard way to change it after it is constructed.

The closest you can get is the ES5 method `Object.create`.

```
var bar = {baz: []};
var foo = Object.create(bar);
```

is in every way equivalent to

```
var foo, bar = {baz: []};
(function () {
    function Foo() {}
    Foo.prototype = bar;
    foo = new Foo;
})();
```

and creates an object `foo` whose prototype is (opaquely and immutably) `bar`.